# Samsung Gingerbread stock browser doesn't fire keypress on enter

Tags: android, html, web, android-2.3-gingerbread

So I am having an issue with the samsung gingerbread stock browser not firing keypress events on dom elements.

Specifically I have an input field and a keypress listener on it. When a user types a litter the keypress function is triggered correctly but when they press the enter key no event is fired.

I have also tested it with textarea elements and it does the same thing.

This appears to be something specific to the samsung browser as I have tested it on a nexus one and it works fine.

html code:

```
<input type="text" class = "textArea commentTextInput" name="newComment" placeholder="enter your comment here"></input>
```

javascript code(I am using zepto which is almost identical to jquery)

```
$(".commentTextInput", this.el).keyup(
    function(e)
{
        console.log("key pressed" + e.which);
    }
);
```

any ideas what could be causing this/how to fix it?

Comment: Did you happen to find out what caused this? I'm running into the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S running Gingerbread.